# C : Elf, sh_addr with offset

Tags: c, elf

If you start your objdump -s from an executable, you will find (in a lot of informations) this :

```
Contents of section .interp:
 400238 2f6c6962 36342f6c 642d6c69 6e75782d  /lib64/ld-linux-
 400248 7838362d 36342e73 6f2e3200           x86-64.so.2.
```

The fact is, I am really interested in :

```
400238
400248
```

Let stop talking and watch the code :

```
void            show_addr(t_all *all)
{
  char          *try;
  char          *secname;
  int           i;
  size_t        point;
  unsigned int          k;

  i = 1;
  all->shdr = (Elf64_Shdr *)(all->data + all->elf->e_shoff);
  secname = (char *)(all->data + all->shdr[all->elf->e_shstrndx].sh_offset);
  while (i < all->elf->e_shnum)
  {
    printf("Contents of section %s: \n", &secname[all->shdr[i].sh_name]);
    try = (char *)(all->data + all->shdr[i].sh_offset);
    point = all->shdr[i].sh_offset;
    k = point;
    while (k < (all->shdr[point].sh_size))
    {
      printf("%x\n", (unsigned int)all->shdr[k].sh_addr);
      k += 16;
    }
  printf("\n");
  i++;
  }
}
```

Well, of course, this code won't work because I'm stuck at this point.
Let me explain a bit :
secname is used to show the name of the section, like ".interp" in my exemple.
all is my own structure with different informations not really usefull here, expect for the call to Elf_64.
"try" and "point" are made to recup the offset (begining) of the section. But when I have it, I don't know how to print this moth** fu**** addr (I'm on since the begining of the day).

Comment: I am not you use to stackoverflow, I saw the flux of questions, does I have to update the subject ?

Comment: What *is* your question? And please keep expletives out of it.